Monomorphism which is locally of finite presentation
$\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}$Let $X$ be an affine scheme of finite type over a field. Let $Y\to X$ be a monomorphism of schemes, which is locally of finite presentation. Is it true that $f$ is quasi-compact? If $X$ is not of finite type, then $f$ is not necessarily quasi-compact, e.g. $\coprod_{i\in I} \Spec(k_i)\to \Spec(\prod_{i\in I}k_i)$ where each $k_i$ is a field and $I$ is an infinite set. But I am not quite sure what happens if $X$ is of finite type over a field.

The inclusion $\coprod_{x \in X^{\text{cl}}} {x} \to X$ from the disjoint union of all closed points is a monomorphism and locally of finite presentation, but not quasi-compact.
